# Android - Debug over remote desktop

Tags: android, adb, desktop

I have spent about the past two hours googling this and have not succeeded in finding a working solution. Basically my situation is I am a contractor for a company and work remotely a couple days a week, but still need to do development on my computer at the office. Basically my phone is plugged into my laptop, and my laptop is running a remote desktop through Citrix. Is there a way to debug on my device plugged into my laptop? I would really like to avoid having to debug it with the google emulators...

Comment: you may be able to share usb devices over windows remote desktop, but because you're using citrix I'm not sure.

Comment: Is it not possible to check out a local copy of your repo to your laptop? Not sure what company policy is but that is what I do for my work.

Comment: Unfortunately they are using Xamarin for development and the license is on the workstation in the office. That's why I have to remote in.

Comment: Bump : did you find a way ?
(in work at home situation, I still haven't found a way to debug a local Android device from the Citrix remote desktop)

Comment: @midiphony No sadly, I never did find a way to do it. I've been doing web development the last few years so there might be a solution now, but there wasn't one when I was looking.